# C# BigInteger remainder as fraction

Tags: c#, biginteger, fractions

**Before you read**, please be aware that I'm aware of the differences between integer and floating-point division, and I'm aware of how `BigInteger.DivRem` and `BigInteger.Divide`.

Consider the following code examples:

```
BigInteger a = new(5);
BigInteger b = new(2);

BigInteger div = BigInteger.DivRem(a, b, out BigInteger rem);

Console.WriteLine($"{div}.{rem}");
```

Output = `2.1`

```
BigInteger a = new(5678);
BigInteger b = new(1234);

BigInteger div = BigInteger.DivRem(a, b, out BigInteger rem);

Console.WriteLine($"{div}.{rem}");
```

Output = `4.742`

Neither of the outputs is correct **(in the context of what I'm asking)**. Sure, they're correct in the sense that they're displaying a division and a remainder formatted as `${div}.{rem}`, but in my case, that's not what I'm looking for.

The correct values would be `2.5` and `4.6012965964` (with a scale of 10 digits) respectively.

Is there a way to convert/represent the remainder as a fractional value, rather than as a remainder?

Note: I know there is `float`, `double` and `decimal`, but those aren't the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think "5 divided by 2 is 2 with a remainder 1" is incorrect.

Comment: You know you're using the `DevRem` method, not `Divide`, right?

Comment: @gunr2171 5/2 = 2.5 not 2.1, and yes, DivRem returns both the result of the division and the remainder. Divide would only return the result of the division, without a remainder, which isn’t what I need.

Comment: `5/2` is 2 with integer division. `5/2` with your calculator is 2.5. `5%2` is 1. You're never going to get "2.1".

Comment: @gunr2171 okay let me put it another way, I’m building a BigDecimal implementation. The underlying type is BigInteger with a separate value to represent scale. Again, I’m aware of how integer and decimal division works. I’m still looking for a solution that allows me to divide one BigInteger by another and preserve the fractional component, NOT the remainder.

Comment: Looks like you need `BigRational` which only exists as a CodePorject, it is not standard.

Comment: I think that your question would be better if it was presented in a positive way. Instead of presenting a nonsensical string concatenation of a quotient and a reminder, and saying *"this is not what I am looking for"*, you could start by simply explaining what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```cs
BigInteger a = new(5678);
BigInteger b = new(1234);

BigInteger div = BigInteger.DivRem(a, b, out BigInteger rem);

var decimalDigits = new List<BigInteger>();

while (rem != 0 && decimalDigits.Count < 10)
{
    rem *= 10;
    decimalDigits.Add(BigInteger.DivRem(rem, b, out rem));
}

Console.WriteLine($"{div}.{string.Concat(decimalDigits)}");
```

This is pretty much just an implementation of long division.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood - what you are doing is integer arithmetic on big integers and the results are correct. Read here [Math.DivRem()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.divrem?view=net-6.0) (to understand DIV and REM as concepts, forget about integral type for now).

What you seem to be after is a floating point type with precision greater than `double`.  Last time I looked no such type exists in .Net, except for a few privateer efforts like [QPFloat](https://github.com/coder0xff/QPFloat)

Comment: Nope, I have not misunderstood. I’m aware how DivRem works, I just want the result of the division represented as a decimal value, which is what I’m asking; is it possible to obtain such a value from a BigInteger, and what computation would need to be done to obtain it.

Comment: Also .NET has a built-in, 128-bit `decimal` type.

Comment: No.  Integer type -> integer operations -> integer results.  To get a floating point result you must work with (convert to) floating point type and operations.  If you just drop the "Big" part of your question and think basic C/C++/C# - instead of `5 / 2` (div) and `5 % 2` (rem) you want `5.0 / 2.0 == 2.5 // or (double)5 / 2` (where you tell the language "cast to floating point, apply floating point operations").

Comment: See the accepted answer, which is essentially what I was looking for. Now I just need to make it performant.

Comment: See 2nd link in my answer for a decent effort. "I just need to make it performant" is far from trivial (has been the topic of computer science papers for many years).  In the Java world there is bigfloat and there are numeric libraries in other languages including one in C++'s boost which I have used, just none available in .Net that are free and bullet-proof AFAIK. Good luck.

Comment: There is no need for `QPFloat` (at least in my opinion), since it represents a 128-bit floating-point value, and .NET has had one of those natively, built into the framework since day one (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netframework-1.1). You are correct, there is `BigDecimal` in Java, but essentially, that's what I'm building in .NET; an arbitrarily sized decimal value.